# Gradient background ignoring circled border

Tags: html, css

I have 3 css classes.

```
.gradiented_block_gray{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, rgb(220, 220, 220));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(white, rgb(220, 220, 220));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(white, rgb(220, 220, 220));
    background: linear-gradient(white, rgb(220, 220, 220));
    border: solid;
    border-color: #dcdcdc;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 100%;
}

.gradiented_block_blue{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(0, 111, 174), rgb(80, 149, 207));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(0, 111, 174), rgb(80, 149, 207));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(0, 111, 174), rgb(80, 149, 207));
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(0, 111, 174), rgb(80, 149, 207));
    width: 100%;
}

.circled_border{
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

I'm using

```
<table class="gradiented_block_gray circled_border" style="border: none">
    <tr>
        <td class="gradiented_block_blue">
```

Without trying to make that `td` being blue gradiented it works okay.
Lower edges of table still circled, but upper is squared.
I want to make upper edges circled too.
Here how it looks like
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a border-radius to `gradiented_block_blue` as well. (But only on the top)

Comment: Thanks. It works. But btw I want to understand why that happend.

Comment: It's because the TD is rendered on top. A table layout consists of multiple layers which are rendered on top of each other, the table itself being the lowest one. And since you gave the `<td>` a background, it simply hides / overlays the round corner on the table layer.